# What is the modern way to filter QuerySet inside custom QuerySet class in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a custom `QuerySet` class which is later used to create an objects manager in actual model somewhat like this:

```
class FooQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    # some stuff in here ...

class Foo(models.Model):
    objects = FooQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Now, I'd like to apply some `filter` like `filter(active=True)` to all `QuerySet` results from `FooQuerySet` without creating a Manager class, however it's not described in Django docs and I've not been able to find what I need in resources I've found on Internet.

Comment: This is untested... but to automatically filter all queries..in FooQuerySet.__init__ could you set ```self = self.filter(active=True)```?

Comment: You'll always end up creating a manager, even if it's a simple manager.